# Error while linking main file with my header file : undefined reference to `myHeaderFunction'

Tags: c, header-files

I am trying to make my first header file in C.

There are three files in same directory.

myHeaderFile.h

```
// It is a good practise to only declare function in header file. 
int myHeaderFunction();
```

myHeaderFile.c

```
#include "myHeaderFile.h"

int myHeaderFunction()
{
    return 1;
}
```

main.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"myHeaderFile.h"

int main()
{
    printf("main function.\n");
    int output;
    output = myHeaderFunction();
    printf("%d\n",output);
    return 0;
}
```

Cronology:

1. I created the first file `myHeaderFile.h` and saved it.
2. Then I created `myHeaderFile.h` and saved it.
3. Then, I created `main.h` and saved it. (I didn't run any of the file above'
4. I opened console and wrote the command as written below.
5. Then, I run `main.h` and it gave the error as mentioned below.

I open the console in the same directory and type:

```
gcc -Wall -o combined main.c myHeaderFile.c
```

It creates a file named combined.exe

And then I run main.c and it gives an error

```
undefined reference to `myHeaderFunction'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

There are few answers for the error
`` undefined reference to `myHeaderFunction' `` but it involves too many function and files and gcc commands that I didn't understood as a begineer.
So I request not to close this answer and give a solution specific to this problem.

Comment: "And then I run main.c" - what does this mean? You run executable programs, you don't run source files.

Comment: You are on Windows, right? Shouldn't output binary be with `.exe` extension (`-o combined.exe`)?

Comment: "_All the files are created and stored in the same manner as shown here._" - Does the example you provided in question also produce this error?

Comment: @Crowman I open the file in VS Code (which had code), and press CTRL+ALT+N which I think is the command for run. But, does that give any information in solving the problem?

Comment: @Jorengarenar I am on windows. The `combined` file which is created is of extension `.exe` i.e. once I open the directory containing the code I can see a file `combined.exe`. If that is what you are asking.

Comment: @Ash OK, but my second question is more important

Comment: @Jorengarenar I understand the confusion. I edited the question to clarify. The example provided in the question *is* the code which is giving me the error.

Comment: @Ash "_I run `main.h`" - shouldn't be "_I run `combined.exe`_"?

Comment: @Jorengarenar When I double click(run) `combined.exe` it doesn't do anything. Anyhow, the objective here of creating a header file is to include the header file into `main.c` and run `main.c` and see it gives me the desired output of `1`. So that is why I run `main.c`.

Comment: @Ash You **cannot** run `main.c` - it's source code, not executable. `combined.exe` is produced program, it's what you want to run. And it doesn't do nothing. It probably does, but does it so fast, it closes before you even manage to see it (it opens new console, prints and then console closes as program finished its work). Run `./combined.exe` from console instead of double clicking.

Comment: @Ash: Yes, it gives information. Your problem is nothing to do with header files, and everything to do with you not understanding what your editor is doing. Follow Jogengarenar's suggestion and run `combined.exe` from the console, because what you're trying to do with CTRL+ALT+N seems to be attempting to build and run an executable from a single source file, and this is exactly what you don't want to do when you have a program split over multiple source files.